# Introducing fixed representation for a quotient type in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

This question is better explained with an example. Suppose I want to prove the following lemma:

```
lemma int_inv: "(n::int) - (n::int) = (0::int)"
```

How I'd informally prove this is something along these lines:

*Lemma: **n - n = 0**, for any integer n and 0 = abs_int(0,0).*

*Proof:

Let **abs_int(a,b) = n** for some fixed natural numbers **a** and **b**.

--- some complex and mind blowing argument here ---

That means it suffices to prove that **a+b+0 = a+b+0**, which is true by reflexivity.

QED.*

However, I'm having trouble with the first step "*Let **abs_int(a,b) = n***". The `let` statement doesn't seem to be made for this, as it only allows one term on the left side, so I'm lost at how I could introduce the variables *a* and *b* in an arbitrary representation for *n*.

How may I introduce a fixed reprensentation for a quotient type so I may use the variables in it?

---

*Note: I know the statement above can be proved by `auto`, and the problem may be sidestepped by rewriting the lemma as "lemma int_inv: "Abs_integ(a,b) - Abs_integ(a,b) = (0::int)". However, I'm looking specifically for a way to prove by introducing an arbitrary representation in the proof.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can introduce a concrete representation with the theorem `int.abs_induct`. However, you almost never want to do that manually.

The general method of proving statements about quotients is to first state an equivalent theorem about the underlying relation, and then use the transfer tool. It would've helped if your example wasn't automatically discharged by automation... in fact, let's create our own little `int` type so that it isn't:

```
theory Scratch
  imports Main
begin

quotient_type int = "nat × nat" / "intrel"
  morphisms Rep_Integ Abs_Integ
proof (rule equivpI)
  show "reflp intrel" by (auto simp: reflp_def)
  show "symp intrel" by (auto simp: symp_def)
  show "transp intrel" by (auto simp: transp_def)
qed

lift_definition sub :: "int ⇒ int ⇒ int"
  is "λ(x, y) (u, v). (x + v, y + u)"
  by auto

lift_definition zero :: "int" is "(0, 0)".
```

Now, we have

```
lemma int_inv: "sub n n = zero"
  apply transfer
```

```
proof (prove)
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. ⋀n. intrel ((case n of (x, y) ⇒ λ(u, v). (x + v, y + u)) n) (0, 0)
```

So, the version we want to prove is

```
lemma int_inv': "intrel ((case n of (x, y) ⇒ λ(u, v). (x + v, y + u)) n) (0, 0)"
  by (induct n) simp
```

Now we can transfer it with

```
lemma int_inv: "sub n n = zero"
  by transfer (fact int_inv')
```

Note that the `transfer` proof method is *backtracking* — this means that it will try many possible transfers until one of them succeeds. Note however, that this backtracking doesn't apply across separate `apply` commands. Thus you will always want to write a transfer proof as `by transfer something_simple`, instead of, say `proof transfer`.

You can see the many possible versions with

```
apply transfer
back back back back back
```

Note also, that if your theorem mentions constants about `int` which weren't defined with `lift_definition`, you will need to prove a transfer rule for them separately. There are some examples of that [here](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/library/HOL/HOL-ex/Transfer_Int_Nat.html).

In general, after defining a quotient you will want to "forget" about its underlying construction as soon as possible, proving enough properties by transfer so that the rest can be proven without peeking into your type's construction.

Comment: A ton of useful info on proving with quotient types, great one! Could expand on the phrase *"[...] **Note however, that this backtracking doesn't apply across separate apply commands**. Thus you will always want to write a transfer proof as by transfer something_simple [...]"*, I didn't quite get what you meant there.

Comment: @Luiz I mean that when transfer has many possible goals it will accept, using something like `by transfer simp` will allow it to try all of them until one succeeds, while `apply transfer` followed by `apply simp` will only work if the first form transfer tries turns out to be the right one.

Comment: Got it. I've also asked a [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67244827/what-does-case-of-mean-in-isabelle) on "`case _ of _`", since I was not able to understand it.