# What does "case _ of _" mean in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

While reading [this answer on quotient types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67237629/14656198), I stumbled upon the construct "`case _ of _ ⇒ _`". Upon checking [the manual](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/isar-ref.pdf), there's no such definition, but there are separate definitions for "`case _`" (§6.5.1) and "`of _`" (§6.4.3). Nonetheless, reading these definitions only confused me more about the meaning of this construct.

Consequently, I decided to come up with a simpler version of the lemma that I might be able to prove, which was this one:

```
lemma test: "(case n of (0::nat,0::nat) ⇒ (a,b) = n) ⟹ a = 0 ∧ b = 0"
```

In my head, after analyzing the context of the mentioned question, this statement should be equivalent to `"(a,b) = (0,0) ⟹ a = 0 ∧ b = 0"`, which should be trivial to prove. Well, *sledgehammer* begs to differ:

```
"cvc4": Timed out 
"z3": Timed out 
"e": Timed out 
"spass": Timed out 
"remote_vampire": The prover gave up
```

So it seems like I'm misunderstanding what this construct is meant to represent.

In light of that, what is the meaning of the statement "`case _ of _ ⇒ _`" in Isabelle?

Comment: After some study, I realize the statement above does not mean what I first thought. For those interested, this is the correctly written version of my example statement:
`lemma test_correct: "(case n of (a,b) ⇒ (a,b) = (0,0)) ⟹ n = (0,0)" by blast`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Isabelle, a statement of the type `case _ of _ ⇒ _ | _ ⇒ _ | _ ⇒ _ | ...`  is a form of pattern matching.

You might want to take a look at §2.5.4 of [Isabelle's tutorial](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/tutorial.pdf) (§2.5.5 and §2.5.6 are also useful). [This question on pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502354/what-is-pattern-matching-in-functional-languages) and [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching) may provide more information about pattern matching in general.

What you are missing is that there not guarantee that the patterns are exhaustive. If no pattern matches, the result is `undefined`.

Nitpick actually finds a counter-example automatically on your lemma:

```
Nitpicking formula... 
Kodkod warning: Interrupt 
Nitpick found a counterexample:
  Free variables:
    a = 1
    b = 0
    n = (0, 1)
```

Let's plugin back the value of n:

```
lemma ‹(case (0,1) of (0::nat,0::nat) ⇒ (a,b) = n)⟹ a = 0 ∧ b = 0›
  apply simp
(*
proof (prove)
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. undefined ⟹ a = 0 ∧ b = 0
*)
```

EDIT, to answer the question below:
`(case (0,1) of (0::nat,0::nat) ⇒ (a,b) = n)` means roughly [1]:

```
(case_prod (0,1) of 
   (0::nat,0::nat) ⇒ (a,b) = n
 | _               ⇒ undefined)
```

where `case_prod` is the destructor for pairs. Hence, if you don't match any of the patterns, the result is undefined.

[1] full output:

```
ML ‹@{term ‹(case (0,1) of (0::nat,0::nat) ⇒ (a,b) = n)›}›
```

Comment: Although you found the problem in my example, I'd appreciate a high level description of what the statement "`case _ of _`" actually means, as "`case (0,1) of (0::nat,0::nat)`" doesn't even make sense to me (maybe you can use it as an example in the explanation). I'm actually slightly more confused than before.

Comment: I thought that `If no pattern matches, the result is undefined.` would answer your question. I will extend my answer.

Comment: I wasn't aware that `case _ of _` was used for pattern matching in Isabelle. I've suggested an edit to clarify and to add some further resources for future readers about Isabelle's case expressions and pattern-matching in general.

Comment: I am curious now: what did you expect that case was doing that is not pattern matching?

Comment: I had no expectations. When I saw pattern matching, in both *Coq* and *Isabelle*, I only saw it with the syntax `fun _ where _` or `match _ with _`, but never `case _ of _`, so I just didn't know what it meant.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, `nitpick` is helpful here. Luckily the fix is simple.

```
lemma test: "(case n of (0::nat,0::nat) ⇒ (a,b) = n | _ ⇒ False) ⟹ a = 0 ∧ b = 0"
```

Because you don't bind any variables, rewriting your hypothesis into a conditional statement is trivial. Finally, you might want to look into the concept of *pattern matching*, specifically in the context of functional programming.

```
lemma test': "(case n of (0::nat,0::nat) ⇒ (a,b) = n | _ ⇒ (a,b) = (0,0)) = ((a,b) = (0,0))"

lemma test'': "(case n of (0::nat,0::nat) ⇒ (a,b) = n) = (if n = (0,0) then (a,b) = n else undefined)"
```